# toFront() method does'nt work with a splash screen use in java fx

Tags: java, javafx, splash-screen

I want to create a simple poke where I have a **splash screen (like an adobe one) that leads to a multi screen application**.

To do so here's my main class `ScreensFramework` :

```
public class ScreensFramework extends Application {


public static String screen1ID = "main";
public static String screen1File = "Screen1.fxml";
public static String screen2ID = "screen2";
public static String screen2File = "Screen2.fxml";
public static String screen3ID = "screen3";
public static String screen3File = "Screen3.fxml";

private Pane splashLayout;
private Stage mainStage;


@Override
public void init() {
    ImageView splash = new ImageView(new Image("http://www.versluis.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/CCsplash-610x520.png"));
    splashLayout = new VBox();
    splashLayout.getChildren().addAll(splash);
    splashLayout.setEffect(new DropShadow());
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
    showSplash(primaryStage);

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(2500),
            ae -> showMainStage(primaryStage)));
    timeline.play();
}

private void showMainStage(Stage initStage) {
    initStage.hide();
    mainStage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    mainStage.setTitle("My Test");
    mainStage.setIconified(true);

    ScreensController mainContainer = new ScreensController();

    mainContainer.loadScreen(ScreensFramework.screen1ID, ScreensFramework.screen1File);
    mainContainer.loadScreen(ScreensFramework.screen2ID, ScreensFramework.screen2File);
    mainContainer.loadScreen(ScreensFramework.screen3ID, ScreensFramework.screen3File);

    mainContainer.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen1ID);

    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().addAll(mainContainer);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    mainStage.setScene(scene);
    mainStage.show();
    mainStage.toFront();

}

private void showSplash(Stage initStage) {
    Scene splashScene = new Scene(splashLayout);
    initStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    initStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    splashScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    initStage.setScene(splashScene);
    initStage.show();
}

/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Things are working pretty fine, except for one thing :

```
mainStage.toFront();
```

When this is called, **my icon flash in orange but the window does not come in front**. So basically I have my splash screen and then nothing if I don't click my self on the windows icon.

Where does it come from ?

Comment: `toFront()` is platform specific, and will behave differently. On Windows, this is the way they handle it.

Comment: There's even a ["bug report"](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8124521) about this.